# ld: 8 duplicate symbols for architecture i386

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, static-libraries

I gone through question already asked on forum. Getting error as below

```
ld: 8 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

More error description is below

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/Documents/Sprint1/iPhone/MyApplication/MyApplication/lib/lib'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-Lrestkit'
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/Documents/Sprint1/iPhone/MyApplication/MyApplication/lib/lib restkit/libRestKit.a, missing required architecture i386 in file /Users/Documents/Sprint1/iPhone/MyApplication/MyApplication/lib/lib restkit/libRestKit.a (2 slices)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_Reachability.reachabilityRef in:
    /Users/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApplication-bchgbqjzuwjzbcbnhwyihhatsoyw/Build/Intermediates/MyApplication.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApplication.build/Objects-normal/i386/Reachability.o
    /Users/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApplication-bchgbqjzuwjzbcbnhwyihhatsoyw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPOSNirvanaUtils.a(Reachability.o)
duplicate symbol _kReachabilityChangedNotification in:
    /Users/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApplication-bchgbqjzuwjzbcbnhwyihhatsoyw/Build/Intermediates/MyApplication.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApplication.build/Objects-normal/i386/Reachability.o
    /Users/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApplication-bchgbqjzuwjzbcbnhwyihhatsoyw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPOSNirvanaUtils.a(Reachability.o)
duplicate symbol _kInternetConnection in:
    /Users/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApplication-bchgbqjzuwjzbcbnhwyihhatsoyw/Build/Intermediates/MyApplication.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApplication.build/Objects-normal/i386/Reachability.o
    /Users/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApplication-bchgbqjzuwjzbcbnhwyihhatsoyw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPOSNirvanaUtils.a(Reachability.o)
duplicate symbol _kLocalWiFiConnection in:
    /Users/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApplication-bchgbqjzuwjzbcbnhwyihhatsoyw/Build/Intermediates/MyApplication.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApplication.build/Objects-normal/i386/Reachability.o
    /Users/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApplication-bchgbqjzuwjzbcbnhwyihhatsoyw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPOSNirvanaUtils.a(Reachability.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_Reachability.key_ in:
    /Users/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApplication-bchgbqjzuwjzbcbnhwyihhatsoyw/Build/Intermediates/MyApplication.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApplication.build/Objects-normal/i386/Reachability.o
    /Users/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApplication-bchgbqjzuwjzbcbnhwyihhatsoyw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPOSNirvanaUtils.a(Reachability.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_Reachability in:
    /Users/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApplication-bchgbqjzuwjzbcbnhwyihhatsoyw/Build/Intermediates/MyApplication.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApplication.build/Objects-normal/i386/Reachability.o
    /Users/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApplication-bchgbqjzuwjzbcbnhwyihhatsoyw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPOSNirvanaUtils.a(Reachability.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Reachability in:
    /Users/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApplication-bchgbqjzuwjzbcbnhwyihhatsoyw/Build/Intermediates/MyApplication.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApplication.build/Objects-normal/i386/Reachability.o
    /Users/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApplication-bchgbqjzuwjzbcbnhwyihhatsoyw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPOSNirvanaUtils.a(Reachability.o)
duplicate symbol _kConnectionDown in:
    /Users/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApplication-bchgbqjzuwjzbcbnhwyihhatsoyw/Build/Intermediates/MyApplication.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApplication.build/Objects-normal/i386/Reachability.o
    /Users/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApplication-bchgbqjzuwjzbcbnhwyihhatsoyw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPOSNirvanaUtils.a(Reachability.o)
ld: 8 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have project structure like

1. Application
2. Static library A
3. Static library B

Situation 
1) Static library A depend on static library B. The project A require Reachability check.
2) Added static library A into Application project
3) When I compile,getting linker error

Please help to resolve this issue.

Comment: You need to give more details of the libraries and what is imported into the project main. What are the libraries (RestKit & Reachability?)

Comment: I think there are more than one file in the Reachability class with the same name try to delete the files

Comment: Have you added reachability in one place, I mean either any of the libraries or in project?

Comment: @Shankar Shinde are you building libPOSNirvanaUtils.a?

Comment: have you added any shell script to build any library?

Answer (score 1):

If this solution is not working then check this..

Another reason this error often happens is accidentally importing the .m file instead of the .h.

Comment: You post both the solutions in the answer section. No need to post answers again and again. Instead of that you update your last answer itself.

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1.Check Build phases in Target settings.

2.Check if any file exists twice or once.

3.If file exist twice delete one. If not delete file in the bottom which is the latest one.

4.Build again.

Answer (score 0):

You have `Reachability` class in `libPOSNirvanaUtils.a` & your Application and you are using `libPOSNirvanaUtils.a` in your application. So now your application has 2 reference of `Reachability` class.

If you are building `libPOSNirvanaUtils.a` then you can solve this with 2 ways:

1. Remove `Reachability` class membership from target `libPOSNirvanaUtils.a`
2. Add `Reachability` class in Copy files, remove `Reachability` class reference from your Application and use same class reference from libPOSNirvanaUtils.

Comment: How do i remove "Reachability" class from libPOSNirvanaUtils.a, for compilation that class require. I do not get your second point about Copy files.

Comment: Keep Reachability class in project just remove Target membership of libPOSNirvanaUtils.

Comment: For #2, go to build phases of target libPOSNirvanaUtils then expand Copy files. By clicking + you can add header files, those files will be copied in include folder that is at the same level where your libPOSNirvanaUtils.a get created.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while using prepareforsegue delegate. It turns out, I accidentally imported the .m file instead of the .h file. This will fix it. Look at your #import statements before you go crazy adding and deleting frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I got this error because had the same named variables declared in several files in implementation part.

```
@implementation A
int a;
...

@implementation B
int a;
...
```

gave me "duplicate symbol _a ..."